# How to read from text file and store in String array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader, filereader

I have a text file textfile.txt which contains data as follows :

```
A-abc , A-xyz , B-mno , A-ijk , B-pqr
```

Now, i have to read from this file and store the values in two separate arrays `"A"` and `"B"` , such that the values with prefix `"A-"` gets stored in array A and values with prefix "B-" gets stored in array B.

Also, while storing the data, the prefix needs to be removed i.e. only `"abc"` needs to be stored in `array A`.

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:\opt\New_Workspace\Salary.txt"); 
// use DataInputStream to read binary NOT text
// DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
String strLine;
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
String[] arrayLine1= strLine.split(" , ");
for(String s:arrayLine1)

String[] arrayLine2 = s.split(": ");
{
if(s.matches("Basic: "))
{
basic = Double.parseDouble(arrayLine[1]);                 
}
else if(s.matches("Perc-D ");
{
percD = Double.parseDouble(arrayLine[3]);                
}
else if(s.matches("Perc-A: "))
{
percA = Double.parseDouble(arrayLine[5]);                 
}

}
```

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried ?

Comment: show us what have you tried?

Comment: I think when people ask for help you should not weigh in on their reason or impress your views on how people learn as a crutch to down vote a perfectly good question because we disagree with the intention the program is being written for.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :-

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

    String strLine;
    String[] filearray;
    filearray = new String[10];

    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

    for (int j = 0; j < myarray.length; j++){
    filearray[j] = br.readLine();
    }

    }
    in.close();
```

Comment: I think we should encourage people to try these simple things, let them post their code, and help if they have some issue. By doing their assignments we ensure, that they don't learn. :) +1

Answer (score 0):

This was written in a hurry, so please pardon any errors:

```
String aStore = "";
String bStore = "";
String aFinal[];
String bFinal[];
try{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
    while(input.hasNextLine()){
        String message = input.nextLine();
        message = message.replace(" ", "");
        String store[] = message.split(",");
        for(int a = 0; a < store.length; a++){
            if((store[a]).contains("A-"){
                String t[] = (store[a]).split("-");
                aStore = aStore + "_" + t[1];
            }
            if((store[a]).contains("B-"){
                String t[] = (store[a]).split("-");
                bStore = bStore + "_" + t[1];
            }
        }
        aFinal = aStore.split("_");
        bFinal = bStore.split("-");
    }
    input.close();
}
catch(Exception e){}
```